# What are examples of Esperanto-given names?

Tags: culture, literature, nouns

I am looking for Esperanto given names, e.g., used in Esperanto literature or as esperantisations of real names. What are examples besides Ludoviko?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are all the given names that appear in the Fundamento de Esperanto. I list them in the form in which they appear there, i.e. sometimes with contracted ending (e.g. Henriet' instead of Henrieto), if that is how they appear in the Fundamento.

Male given names:

- Aleksandro
- Antono
- Aŭgusto
- Ernesto
- Georgo
- Izraelo
- Johano
- Jozefo
- Ludoviko
- Nikodemo
- Nikolao
- Paŭlo
- Petro
- Stefano
- Teodoro
- Vilhelmo

Female given names:

- Anno
- Berto
- Elizabeto
- Emili'
- Henriet'
- Klaro
- Mario
- Paŭlino
- Sofio

Additionally, the Fundamento lists multiple nicknames formed with "-ĉjo" of "-njo", e.g. "Joĉjo" and "Manjo".

I used a [blog post by Bernardo](http://www.ipernity.com/blog/bernardo/285340) as a reference for the above lists. (The blog by Bernardo provides a lot of useful esperantological information, especially about the Fundamento de Esperanto, but unfortunately Bernardo is often (though not in the blog post I just linked) quite aggressive in his remarks about esperantologists that he disagrees with, especially about members of the Akademio de Esperanto.)

Answer (score 5):

Any name can be 'esperantised', usually by adding an -o, and transliterating the sounds with the respective Eo approximations. Double letters seem to be dropped.

I'm just looking at Chris Gledhill's translation of *The Hobbit* (*La Hobito*), and some of the names there are *Bilbo Baginzo* (Bilbo Baggins), *Golumo* (Gollum), *Smauxgo* (Smaug), *Gandalfo*, *Dvalino* (Dwalin), *Torino Kverkasxildo* (Thorin Oakenshield). In the latter example, the translator has also translated the name itself.

A female name (the only I could find...) is that of Shelob the spider (in the appendix of the book): *Sxeloba*. So it seems that in *some* cases the gender of a name is indicated by adding *-a*, perhaps in analogy to Latin? As shown by the other answers, this is not generally the case, though.

Comment: An interesting side-aspect is whether the Eo names have different connotations to the original ones. For example, _Dvalino_ might sound more feminine, as it is homographic to the feminine _-in_ affix. Or is that just me?

Comment: Also to add that as an alternative to *„-o“* and *„-a“*, nicknames can be created by adding *„-ĉjo“* or *„-njo“*.

Comment: "-o" is not just for male names. It is the Esperanto noun ending, and as such does not contain any information about gender. Zamenhof himself used "Mario", "Elizabeto", "Klaro", "Sofio" and other names ending in "-o" as female names. Considering modern usage, there is a female native speaker of Esperanto who calls herself "Heleno" in Esperanto.

Comment: @MarcosCramer Ah, thanks! I had come across female names ending in _-a_ which is why I drew this (incorrect) conclusion.

Comment: @OliverMason: see http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/propraj_nomoj/esperantigitaj.html#i-6ie for more on that topic (in short: it's fine to use names ending with A if they end in A in their native language; in that case we should consider them as un-Esperantized or incompletely Esperantized)